# postinstall in package.json not recognized

Tags: json, node.js, react-native, package.json

I'm working on a react native app and the postinstall value doesn't seem to be recognized.

[image: postinstall value not recognized]

when i run 'npm run ios' I get the following error

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong type of quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes you have are incorrect. They are a UTF8 quote and not the standard ascii quote.

Delete the quotes used in that line and re-type them